# Using vlookup for duplicate values

Tags: excel

I have a dataset which I want to perform VLOOKUP. The problem is that there are duplicates.

[image]

I have this data in "Sheet1".

I performed VLOOKUP in "Sheet2" on the data (picture above) in "Sheet1":

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A15,Sheet1!$A$2:$I$1048576,2,FALSE),"N/A")
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A15,Sheet1!$A$2:$I$1048576,3,FALSE),"N/A")
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the cells B20, C20, B23, and C23 are wrong (0.60% and 0.02% for all, because VLOOKUP only returns the first looked up value). I want B20 to be 0.36%, C20 to be 0.00%, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to do that this is the solution? A second table where you look up values in the first table, but you have multiple instances of the lookup value in both tables and you want excel to guess which one you "meant" it to look up. This seems like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your "Sheet2" cell B15, use this formula and copy over and down (adjust range references to suit your actual data, but don't use whole columns as shown in your original formula):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A15,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,0)),INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$C,SMALL(INDEX((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11=$A15)*ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11),),COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,"<>"&$A15)+COUNTIF($A$15:$A15,$A15)),MATCH(B$14,Sheet1!$B$1:$C$1,0)),"N/A")
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?
What if I want to add the  values in column B and column C for duplicate? I actually want to delete the duplicates and have one stock name with summed Allocation in Portfolio (column B) and MTD Attribution (column C). So column B for stock A should be 1.11% (0.6+0.36+0.15)

Comment: @JunJang Summing duplicate values is much easier, should have led with that.  You just need the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) or a [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) (and it sounds like Pivot Table is going to be your best solution)

Comment: I see. Thanks! How are you so good at Excel? How can I be better?

Comment: @JunJang It's just practice.  I've been working in Excel for about 10 years now.